# Timezone issues and file size differing for spfilezilla

Tags: file-upload, import, spfile

I've uploaded some files from a local server to the Office 365 sharepoint cloud using spfilezilla.

However I notice the times are different by the same offset of a few hours. Would this be a timezone issue?

Also some files have different file sizes. I would hate to lose data so could anyone tell me why this is so? Is it sharepoint altering the files in some way or data corruption. I noticed it with the file uploads via browser as well.